# How to get current account name in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

For example, if my current Colab instance is signed in as

`myColab@gmail.com`

Is it possible to get the name "myColab" in ipython?

What is the command to do this?

I want to do this because I may run two Colab, and they generate files, I want to tag these files with Colab account name, so I know which account generate these files.

Comment: If you can get the email adress in a python variable, you could do a `your_username = your_email.split('@')[0]`

Comment: @nicolallias Thank you for reply. But the problem is how to get email address automatically?

Comment: No idea. Can you show us the result of the `dir()` output?

Comment: @nicolallias dir  shows ['In',
 'Out',
 '_',
 '__',
 '___',
 '__builtin__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 '_dh',
 '_exit_code',
 '_i',
 '_i1',
 '_i2',
 '_i3',
 '_i4',
 '_ih',
 '_ii',
 '_iii',
 '_oh',
 '_sh',
 'auth',
 'exit',
 'get_ipython',
 'project_id',
 'quit']

Answer (score 6):

By default, the backends are not authenticated for any particular user. But, if you've gone through through the `gcloud auth` flow, you can retrieve the email address like so:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VVWs_pcjjz2vg0H2Ti6-12FzcCojRF6a

The key snippet is:

```
import requests
gcloud_token = !gcloud auth print-access-token
gcloud_tokeninfo = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=' + gcloud_token[0]).json()
print(gcloud_tokeninfo['email'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just run following:

```
!gcloud config get-value account
```

Comment: It only works if you logged in with gcloud login command. Byt in some instances you run the code with one account but log in with gcloud login to another one to use resources of the second account. In the latter case, you will see the latter account whereas it should be the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get the current user logged in via the GDrive authenticaiton. I do not wish to push another authentication, just to record the name. I believe OP was attempting the same thing.

My theory was, login with google drive, create a file, then read the file's creator. This does not function as intended, it only returns root:root. But it might spark an idea how to make this work in someone who knows more about python and colab then me.

If you create the file in the directory `MyDrive`, GDrive can see the file and it says owner is `Me`, hovering over me shows the email account. GDrive knows who made it. I can just not figure out how to make colab output the real file owner, even for files already existing in `MyDrive`. I assume it is something to do with the mount being symbolic, but.. there HAS to be a way.

Code

```
print("test", file=open("owner.txt", "a"))
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("owner.txt")
owner = path.owner()
group = path.group()
print(f"{path.name} is owned by {owner}:{group}")
```

Output

```
owner.txt is owned by root:root
```